# How to make cloth bounce off object onto the floor at stabilise

Tags: modifiers, cloth-simulation, collision

I have a cloth which is bouncing off the triangle, but when it hits the floor the cloth goes through. I have applied collision modifier to my floor, just as I have applied collision modifier to my triangle shape.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess the face normals of the floor are pointing in the wrong direction, because it looks as if this once was the inside of a cube.

Comment: if Gordon's advise doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Comment: The normals were facing the correct way, I did the file from the beginning, the collision is correct now, but I lost my settings to make the cloth slip off the object and slide onto the floor.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=odBPR0oo" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/odBPR0oo/)

Comment: @blenderbreath please don't add details to your question in the comments section. Blend files belong in the original post, so add them there with the [edit] button above

Comment: @blenderbreath So is this file related to the original question anymore? The problem was it's falling to the floor. The cloth in the file is neither falling through the floor nor is it the same collision object like the one in the question... Is this actually a new question on how to make cloth slippy?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to undo all the steps, go all the way back, but blender didn't allow more than 30 undos, so I made another file. But I'd like to know how to make  the cloth slippery, thank you.